# Creating complex objects with list and classes in C

Tags: c, list, class, struct

I have a list of flows, and each flow contains a list of requirements.

each requirement contains
**id**: which is the index of flow it is contained in
**type**:   a string or enum representing the type
**resourceId**:  an integer
**instance**: an integer

so if I were to represent in java, could do like

```
List<Flow> flowList = new ArrayList<>()

class Flow
{
  int id;
  List<Requirement> requirementList;

}
class Requirement
{
  int flowID;
   String type;
int resourceId;
int instance;
}
```

**I am not sure how one would do this in C as C doesn't have an inbuilt type

list or classes.** What would be the best way to approach such design in the C
language. Should I use arrays instead of List or use a LinkedList code library that
implements the basic functions, I can directly start using it in my code.
Any ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: you have to find a linked list implementation for c or write one yourself. You cant use c++?

Comment: @pm100 Nopes, I cannot use C++. Where can I find some good implementation for a list, and what about classes I guess could be dealt with `structs.`? Writing complex code seems complicated in a language like C as it doesn't have any inbuilt features.

Comment: The decision between an array and a linked list is going to depend on the usage.  Each has their own advantages.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux linked lists are available out of box already, please see [man 7 queue](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/queue.7.html) for more information. Unfortunately I cannot suggest something similar for Windows as I do not have experience.
See additionally [man 3 queue](https://linux.die.net/man/3/queue) for examples of usage.

Classes you mentioned can be typically converted to structures, of cource possibly with usage of pointer members for conversion of `String` to `char *`, etc.